# Cookie issue with JSoup

Tags: java, cookies, ssl, base64, jsoup

I'm trying to parse multiple pages from a site with basic authentication, know for fact there is a login limit of 8 times per 30 seconds so I need to save a cookie to be able to parse faster than that.

I have wrote a text program just to try out cookies:

```
String login = username + ":" + new String(password);
String base64login = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(login.getBytes()));

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\axis2\\jssecacerts");
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
Map<String, String> cookies = null;

try {   
    Response response = Jsoup
            .connect(
                    "https://url.com/site.html")
            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + base64login)
            .method(Method.POST)
            .execute();

    cookies = response.cookies();   

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
{
    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup
                .connect("https://url.com/site.html")
                .cookies(cookies)
                .get();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

The for loop will access the same page multiple times, It works 8 first times then it gives me an 401 answer. When reading the cookie Map it contains the correct session ID etc.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps, you shouldn't cook Soup with Cookies! :D

Comment: Perhaps just check if the status code is 200 and then proceed with parsing, otherwise reconnect? What exception / stack trace do you get?

Comment: I could suggest you 2 things 1. Send `Authorization` header on each request 2. Instead of using the `Cookies` of the first `Response` could you pass the cookies of the previous response to the next request.